# How to create windows form using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using MySQL for database and codeigniter. I got problem. I want make a new windows form when I click a button or something. so I do this. I use this code in view:

```
function getproductfjs(obj) {
window.open('<?php echo base_url()."index.php/menuppic/get_all_part_po?index=";?>'addressbar=0,location=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1');
}

<tr>
<input type="text" size="20" class="form-control" readonly name="idcust_0" id="idcust_0"  onclick="getproductfjs(this);" placeHolder="Choose Here..."></td>
</tr>
```

-then in controllers:

```
function get_all_part_po(){
        $this->check_page();
        $data['query'] = $this->sj->get_data_allpartpo();
        $this->load->view('ppic/sj/get_all_part_po_view',$data);
    }
```

-then in models:

```
function get_data_allpartpo() {
        $query = $this->db->query("select p.*, c.*, n.*, s.*, c2.*
from tbl_partpo p, tbl_partcustomer c , tbl_nopo n, tbl_schedpo s, tbl_customer c2
where p.id=s.id and c.idpart = p.idpart and n.idnopo = p.idnopo and c2.idcust=c.idcust and qtyscpend <> 0 and c.idcust=1019 ");
        return $query;
    }
```

- I tried the query in database phpmyadmin and its work. the problem is why its not show a new windows form. its just only make a new tab. what I want is make a new windows form when I get click on that placeholder.
  please gimme something that maybe I should know or a link where I can found out my problems.

Comment: `window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");`

Comment: hey @TintuCRaju thank you for your help